# How to properly arrange elements in a Stack in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, layout, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and iOS so probably this is a silly question but I can't get answer to this question anywhere.

This and this is my code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
            Text("Hey there")
            Text("How are you ?")
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
}
```

This is my output

[image]

1. Here how can I move the two text to basically anywhere in this 300x300 box (Vstack)?
2. How do set the `distribution` property to a Stack (In UIKit the `distribution` property aligns the elements in horizontal direction in case of a vertical stack and vice versa).
3. Here I have given `.leading` property but why it does not stick to the left of this box (Vstack) and rather give this result

Answer (score 0):

To make them stick to the left, embed your code in an `HStack` like so:

```
HStack {
    //your code
    Spacer()
}
```

to move them anywhere in the box, use `.padding()`, `.padding(.top, x)` moves them down by x; `.padding(.bottom, x)` moves them up by x. Similarly, `.leading` moves them to the right and `.trailing` to the left.

Use `Spacer()` at the end of a `VStack` to move everything to the top, and at the start of it to move them to the bottom; in an `HStack`, `Spacer()` at the top moves them to the right, and at the bottom moves em to the left.

You can set `Spacer(minLength: x)` to set a minimum length for the spacer. `(V/H)Stack(spacing: y)` sets the space between every view in that `VStack` or `HStack`.
`ZStack` is used to put a `View` on top of another:

```
ZStack {
    Text("Hi")
    Text("Bye")
}
```

This places bye on top of hi!

Comment: Hey thank you for answering, can you answer my third question also that why is it not sticking to the left but instead shows the out as in the above image when given a `.leading` property.   And also adding a `.padding` every time seems little cumbersome and also is error prone is there any other better way to do that ?

Comment: When you specify the alignment to .leading, the elements are placed to the left but still appear in the middle because the VStack takes up only the space it needs.